# change the height of a gridview header row programmatically

Tags: c#, gridview

i am trying to change the height of both the tables cells height and the header rows height with code behind. the code below works only on the cells and not the header rows cells, how can this be done independently please? BTW its an asp.net web app

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN.RowStyle.Height = 30;
    }

    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cell.Width = 150;
        cell.Height = 20;
        cell.Attributes.CssStyle["text-align"] = "center";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the top row height that contains the headers you can use

```
gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN.ColumnHeaderHeight = someInt;
```

To change the vertical header width

```
gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN.RowHeaderWidth = someInt;
```

To change all cell height use

```
gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN.RowHeight = someInt;
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit.** Seeing as this is an ASP.NET application, you want

```
GridView gridView = new GridView();
gridView.HeaderRow.Height = someInt;
```

to set the column header row height.

Comment: i get an  error that ColumnHeaderHeight does not exist This is a web app btw

Comment: Ahh, you failed to mention that. The above works for WPF desktop/metro apps.

Comment: What is the exact type of `gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN`?

Comment: so what would the code i have put up be changed to, because i cannot get it to work, its like the row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header part is not correct?

Comment: with your help i solved this by using gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN.HeaderRow.Height = 30;

Comment: Your answer for Winform is wrong. That will not work unless you set the ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode property.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood your question, can you just select the header row from the GridView?

```
GridviewRow headerRow = gvCurrentStageCircsPSTN.headerRow;
headerRow.Height = whatever you want the height to be.
```

Comment: This is a web app btw (apologies for not mentioning that) and as a result i am getting an error saying gridviewrow cannot be found...